# How to write a Fortran 95 line of code on multiple line?

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I want to write my line of code on multiple line like the code below :

```
print *, v1, v2, v3 &
  & v4,v5
```

Comment: Please always use the tag fortran as less people wil follow the fortran95 tag.

Comment: You're simply missing a comma between `v3` and `v4`, or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100 percent sure what you want but the way of writing a code line over multiple lines is dependent on whether you are using fixed formatted or free formatted code.

In fixed formatted code one would write e.g.

```
      print *, v1, v2, v3,
     1 v4,v5
```

note: the requirement of 6 spaces at the beginning of the line or 5 spaces plus the continuation character (here a 1)

in free formatted code (advised to use):

```
  print *, v1, v2, v3, &
    v4,v5
```

The continuation character (`&`) should be the last non blank character on the line (before optional comment on the line after the `&`).

Hope this solves your problem.